# SVN update of Slim php framework

Tags: php, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, slim

I try to add the Slim PHP framework to a repository but it gives me errors in all the .php files :

For example, for index.php :

```
Commit
......\trunk\web\Slim\index.php
......\trunk\web\Slim\index.php
Commit failed (details follow):
Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:

***********************************
PHP error in: trunk/web/Slim/index.php:
Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in
 trunk/web/Slim/index.php on line 12 Warning: Unexpected character in input:
 '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in trunk/web/Slim/index.php on line 12 Parse error:
 syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in trunk/web/Slim/index.php on line 12
 Errors parsing trunk/web/Slim/index.php
***********************************
This error was generated by a custom hook script on the Subversion server.
Please contact your server administrator for help with resolving this issue.
```

- The server of the repository use PHP 5.3.3
- I am using TortoiseSVN
- index.php on line 12 :  `\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();`

Comment: `This error was generated by a custom hook script on the Subversion server`.  Please research and/or share the custom pre-commit hook.  There's no way for us to help you without seeing that custom code.

Comment: I don't have access to the configuration of the server.

Comment: Wait, that looks like PHP <5.3 throwing an error about namespaces.  Are you 100% sure the repo server is on 5.3.3?  I'm guessing it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the server admin, he disabled some hook scripts on the server, now everything works fine!